# Rename Relationship Class labels

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, relationship-class

Is there a way to rename relationship class labels (forward and Backward labels)  after I've created them ? or I have to delete them and create them again ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on the Arcgis Help, you cannot change relationship class properties that were assign during the creation of relationship class.
Link:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Viewing_and_modifying_relationship_properties/004t0000000q000000/

So, You have to recreate you relationship classes!

Answer (score -1):

Use ArcCatalog to rename relationship classes:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004t0000000r000000

Comment: Thanks Rayner, but that is for The name of the Relationship class. I need to rename the labels (forward and Backward labels)  a property inside the relationship class .